# How to delete a directory path that is giving a access denied error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directory

Bit of backstory into what I am accomplishing I work as an installation tech for Autodesk and I thought it would be fun to create a simple program to help automate the process of clearing out folders normally left behind after the software is uninstalled.

The directories that I am trying to delete are as followed.

```
C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\
C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\
C:\Users\All Users\Autodesk\
C:\Users\**YOUR USERID**\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\
C:\Users\**YOUR USERID**\AppData\Local\Autodesk\
```

This is the code that I have been toying arround with

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        //di.Attributes &= ~FileAttributes.ReadOnly;

        try
        {
            File.SetAttributes("C:/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk", FileAttributes.Normal);
            Directory.Delete("C:/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk", true);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            File.SetAttributes("C:/ProgramData/Autodesk", FileAttributes.Normal);
            Directory.Delete("C:/ProgramData/Autodesk", true);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

For the following line it get this error.

```
File.SetAttributes("C:/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk", FileAttributes.Normal);
```

System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk' is denied.'

If I where to remove that line and use the Directoyr.Delete on it's own I would get this error instead.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path 'AcIPC_2_x86.dll' is denied.'
```

I spend a couple of days poking around trying to figure out how I may allow the software the ability to delete the directories but I feel that i'm at an impasse.

Comment: Are you running this program as an admin.

Comment: I am. However it seems that even if I attempt to publish the program and try running that as an admin it still gives me an access denied error.

Comment: If it says "access is denied", then access is denied. It's that simple. Admin rights usually get you broad access, but it doesn't mean you necessarily have carte blanche. In any case, what you have is a computer configuration problem, not a programming problem. Stack Overflow isn't the right place for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the application as administrator through the code, it might be worth a try:

Add a new item to your project folder and call it "**Application Manifest File**". Then procceed to change this line of code `<requestedExecutionLevel>` to this:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This will prompt the user to allow administrator access (So essentially the same as right clicking on it and click run as administrator)

Comment: This worked!!!! I could kiss you!!!!

Comment: I am so glad it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this isn't the right place for you.  There are reasons why you can get ACCESS_DENIED that can be programmatically overcome.  Keep in mind that unless you are an administrator, you cannot remove files or folders from various directories, including Programs and Programs (x86).  As fluffy said, you can run as an administrator (if you **are** an administrator) explicitly because the natural state of an application is to run non-elevated.  Here is an example of how I have overcome this problem:

```
    public static class FileSystem
    {
        public static void RunAsAdministrator(this Process process, 
                                              string arguments = "")
        {
            if (process == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(process));
            }

            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
                             ProcessStartInfo(process.MainModule.FileName)
            {
                Verb = @"runas",
                Arguments = arguments
            };

        Process.Start(startInfo);


    public static void TakeOwnership(string path)
    {
        if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsAdministrator())
        {
            using (new PrivilegeEnabler(Process.GetCurrentProcess(), Privilege.TakeOwnership))
            {
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
                DirectorySecurity directorySecurity = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();

                if (directorySecurity == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                directorySecurity.SetOwner(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User);
                Directory.SetAccessControl(path, directorySecurity);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Process.GetCurrentProcess().RunAsAdministrator();
        }
    }
}

public static bool IsAdministrator(this AppDomain threadDomain)
{
    threadDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);

    WindowsPrincipal currentPrincipal = (WindowsPrincipal) Thread.CurrentPrincipal;

    if (currentPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator) || currentPrincipal.IsInRole((int) WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainAdminsSid))
    {
        return true;
    }

    using (WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())
    {
        return windowsIdentity.Groups?.Any(windowsIdentityGroup => windowsIdentityGroup.Value.Equals(@"S-1-5-32-544")
                                                                    || windowsIdentityGroup.Value.EndsWith(@"500")
                                                                    || windowsIdentityGroup.Value.EndsWith(@"512")) == true;
    }
}
```

}
If you are already running as an administrator, you can take ownership of the directory immediately, otherwise, there is code include to restart the current process in elevated mode.

I CAUTION YOU THAT DOING IS AT YOUR OWN RISK. Taking ownership is a big deal. The other option is to take a less sledge-hammer approach and modify the ACL on the directory or file(s).

The PrivilegeEnabler code is useful regardless. It can be found [here](http://processprivileges.codeplex.com/).